# How to do this : Run the installation script at <yourdomain.com>/install while installing docker image of lean time

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to install leantime on my ubuntu.

I am following this official documentation:

[Link to it.](https://hub.docker.com/r/leantime/leantime)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZjlI.png)

I have done all the above 3 steps but do not know how to run the fourth command.

The syntax is :

<yourdomain.com>/install

What should I write at <yourdomain.com> as I am installing leantime software locally on my ubuntu.

It is basically to fully setup mysql and network.

Can anyone help me to perform this step number 4?

What is it for and what should I do?

When I run

```
sudo docker images
```

it shows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gktlk.png)

Is leantime and mysql image properly setup on my device properly?
Is there any command to check it?

Regards

Comment: You have the text "enter image description here" in a couple of places in your question.  Can you [edit] the question to replace these links with the actual text of the output you're getting (not an image, not behind a link)?  It'd also be helpful to include the actual application source code you're working on, rather than referring to instructions behind a link.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze I think it is the only possible way to include images.

Comment: Commands like `docker images` don't produce PNG files as their output; you shouldn't need to include images to provide your source code and error messages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.